# codeigniter - use model results in controller to call a different function in the model

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I want to pass a result to a controller from a model after retrieving it from the DB depending on the user input. The values to be returned to the controller will be inserted to another table alongside other variables submitted through the same form. When i try running my code, it gives me the error below. Am using codeigniter 3.0.0

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: controllers/Service_providers.php
Line Number: 68
```

and this one too

```
Error Number: 1048
Column 'bs_name' cannot be null
INSERT INTO `merchants` (`bs_name`, `business_no`, `phone_no`, `location`, `licence_no`, `commission`, `balance`, `email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '4', '4', NULL, '4', '4', '4', 'muokid3@gmail.com', '4', 'e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5')
Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\mafya\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

here is my code:

Controller

```
function add()

    {
        $facility_code = $this->input->post('facilityno');

        $data['fa_details'] = $this->Service_provider_model->getFacilityDetails($facility_code);

        if ($fa_details = null) 
        {
            echo "The Service Provider is not Recognized by the Government";
        }
        else
        {
            foreach ($data['fa_details'] as $detail) 
            {
                $bs_name = $detail->facility_name;
                $location = $detail->district;
            }

            $s_provider = array('bs_name' => $bs_name,
                    'business_no' => $this->input->post('businessno'),
                    'phone_no' => $this->input->post('phoneno'),
                    'location' => $location,
                    'licence_no' => $this->input->post('licenseno'),
                    'commission' => $this->input->post('commission'),
                    'balance' => $this->input->post('balance'),
                    'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
                    'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'password' => md5($this->input->post('password')));

            if ($this->Service_provider_model->save($s_provider)) 
            {
                echo "Service Provider Successfully Added";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "Service Provider NOT Added";
            }
        }


    }
```

model:

```
function getFacilityDetails($facility_code)
    {
        $facility_details = 'facility_details';
        $this->db->where('facility_code', $facility_code);
        return $this->db->get($this->$facility_details);
    }

function save($s_provider){
        $this->db->insert($this->merchants, $s_provider);
        return $this->db->insert_id();
    }
```

Comment: Make your question precise.

Comment: i want to enter a facility number in a form alongside other details: username, password, email etc. The system is suppossed to fetch the business_no and location which are already present in the DB and insert them into another table together with the details that I entered at first. it will fetch the business_no and location where facility_no is the same as the facility_no i entered in the form. If it doesnt exist, it will give me a message that "The Service Provider is not Recognized by the Government". Is it clear now?

Comment: ok i will copy your code and then edit.

Comment: try this [code](https://jsfiddle.net/dgkbgve5/)

Comment: i have tried it and noticed that it's working if i remove the if statement. when the if statement is there, it says "Fatal error: Call to a member function num_rows() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\mafya\application\controllers\Service_providers.php on line 61"

Comment: try this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/dgkbgve5/1/)

Comment: awesome! its now working. in fact the code in the first link works. I was using the variable $data instead of $query. Thanks @Bugfixer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use result_array() or result() function to get value from db so you have change your model like

```
function getFacilityDetails($facility_code)
    {
        $facility_details = 'facility_details';
        $this->db->where('facility_code', $facility_code);
        return $this->db->get($this->$facility_details)->result();
    }
```

Comment: I have tried that but it gives me this error A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: bs_name

Filename: controllers/Service_providers.php

Line Number: 71

Comment: and this one Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: location

Filename: controllers/Service_providers.php

Line Number: 74

Comment: sorry i forget to mention your are using object so change in your model result() function instead of result_array()

Comment: it still doesnt find the variables 'bs_name' and 'location' which are supposed to be fetched from the database

Answer (score 0):

Study about CI 3.0 from [link](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/).There are several new feature added.

For this query bs_name cannot be null so give some value with inverted comma or assign some default value in your table,You dont need to put **null** after that it will automatically take the default value.

```
INSERT INTO `merchants` (`bs_name`, `business_no`, `phone_no`, `location`, `licence_no`, `commission`, `balance`, `email`, `username`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, '4', '4', NULL, '4', '4', '4', 'muokid3@gmail.com', '4', 'e4da3b7fbbce2345d7772b0674a318d5').
```

Remove **bs_name** from query.it will be automatically filled by default value.

For another problem.please make sure your `controller name`  starts with capital letter

eg. Example.php

This is new in [CI 3.0.](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html)

Comment: the values for bs_name and location fields should be fetched from a DB table and inserted into another table with respect to the facilityno

Comment: if your want to insert the value then remove **notnull** attribute from mysql table

Comment: like i mentioned above if table colunmn is assigned NOTNULL then it cannot be empty while inserting data so remove **notnull** attribute from mysql table or assign a default value so whenever is that data is not available for **bs_modal** the default value is inserted.

Comment: and it shouldnt have a default value since each facilityno has its own bs_name and location. which are already in the database

Comment: Check your 1st query then which is giving bs_name and location.that query is not working correctly.if query supplies   bs_name and location everytime than why **NULL** is coming.